# Type casting to datetime

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got data from JSON like "/Date(1285871400000)/" ,but i want to convert in "dd/mm/yyyy".

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data     = "/Date(1285871400000)/",
    stamp    = /Date\((\d+)\)/.exec(data),
    date     = new Date(+stamp[1]);

alert(date.getDate() + "/" + date.getMonth() + "/" + date.getFullYear());
```

Comment: Hey Andy, lots of good answers from you around here, but i keep seeing you push + as cast to int. Imo this is bad practice since people who don't know any better will use it on an octal one day and get very unexpected results. parseInt(string, 10) would be better for teaching people.

Comment: @Martin: Thank very much. For the `+` operator, I made myself clear in one of my blogposts about that: http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2010/11/about-javascript-shortcuts-trickery.html. It's more convenient to me to have a `Number` or (if it isn't a number) `NaN`.

Comment: I generally prefer using the constructor functions instead of operators: `Number(foo)`, `Boolean(foo)`, ... is more explicit than `+foo`, `!!foo`; however, in tight loops, using the operators might be prefarable as these can be dispatched statically...

Comment: @Christoph: yes this will work too, but in terms of performance, `+` is more than twice as fast as using the contructor method: http://jsperf.com/plus-operator-cast-vs-constructor Not to forget about the lazy ones (like me), only one character to type!